# Why is placing an adverb before infinitives sometimes natural, but sometimes awkward?

Tags: infinitives, adverb-placement

The following sentences are quoted from [an blog post](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/32800/infinitives-to-split-or-not) discussing adverb positions for infinitives:

> GOOD: I want you personally to supervise the work that is to be done.

> AWKWARD: I want you carefully to consider Jenkins' proposal to handle all our deliveries.

### Question

Even though both adverbs are in the similar positions (before to+verb), why is the first sentence considered good and the second sentence considered awkward?

Comment: I find them both awkward, victims of the insane prohibition against putting the adverb in its natural place, between "to" and the infinitive.

Comment: ***personally*** functions as an "intensifying" modifier of the object noun ***you*** - it's equivalent to emphatic *you **yourself*** in the cited context. But ***carefully*** is more obviously adverbial, in that it modifies the actual verb ***supervise***, so the two constructions are completely different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You're right - I didn't even notice that reading of the first one.

Comment: @ColinFine: Well, you know the lingo better than me, obviously. Is it still valid to call ***personally*** an "adverb", even though *functionally* speaking it's being used more like a "[pro]noun adjunct" (i.e. - an ***adjectival*** usage) modifying another noun, rather than a verb?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - What you say makes sense, although the blogger actually says that _personally_ is intended to modify _supervise_! I don't agree with him that _I want you to consider carefully Jenkins' proposal to handle all our deliveries._ is awkward.

Comment: @KateBunting: I agree with the blogger that *I want you **carefully to consider...*** is "awkward" - but like you, I don't have a problem with *I want you **to consider carefully...*** But I would say the length of the *other* adverbial element (*Jenkins' proposal to handle all our deliveries*, in this case) massively affects my preference. If that other element was shorter, I'd much prefer to "front" it: *I want you to consider **this proposal** carefully* would usually be more natural to me than *I want you to carefully consider this proposal.*

Comment: @KateBunting: "What you say makes sense, although the blogger actually says that personally is intended to modify supervise!" Thanks for checking out the blog. So what you just pointed out is that FumbleFingers claims **personally** modifies **you**, whereas the blogger claims **personally** modifies **supervise**, so these are different. Do you think these are both possible interpretations or the blogger is simply wrong? FumbleFingers: I would appreciate it if you could comment on this as well.

Comment: Only the writer of the original sentence knows what they intended to say. They are both possible interpretations if _personally_ directly follows _you_ - "I want you and no-one else to do it" or "I want you to supervise in person". (In fact, both mean the same, but with a slight difference in emphasis.)

Comment: @KateBunting: That makes sense. Thank you, it helps a lot!